# onBlur как узнать элемент, по которому кликнули(не текущий элемент)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

по событию onBlur я могу получить текущий элемент, но мне надо запрограммировать разное поведение, в зависимости от того, по какому элементу кликнули.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вам нужен `relatedTarget`: https://jsfiddle.net/yaymer/d6xv2bfe/

```js
let listener = e => {
  console.log(e.relatedTarget);
};

Array.from(
    document.getElementsByTagName("button"), 
    btn => btn.addEventListener("blur", listener));
```

```html
<button>Something</button>
<button>Something2</button>
```

Comment: Ему нужно тот, который получил фокус.

Comment: Нет, это не то, так мы получаем элемент, на котором вызывается событие onBlur, но мне надо получить элемент, на котором кликнули в событии onBlur. То есть при клике на Something2 в функции на событии onBlur кнопки Something я хочу получить Something2  а не Something.

Comment: Всё равно не совсем понял, извиняюсь, но, вероятно, вам нужен `relatedTarget`. Отредактировать ответ не могу - 404, поэтому проверьте вот это - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaymer/d6xv2bfe/).

Comment: Да, похоже, что он. А редактирование должно бы работать.

Comment: @Qwertiy должно, но на всех ответах - 404. :\ Спасибо за правку.

Comment: Напиши об этом на мету - у меня отдельной страницей тоже открывается.

Comment: @Qwertiy выяснил в чём ошибка была - у меня стоит замена UA на Googlebot, вот и не пускало меня.

Comment: Да, ботам ответы редактировать не стоит)))

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, правда я уже сам нашел решение)

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, никак. `document.activeElement` не прокатывает, поэтому остаётся только на фокус подписаться:

```js
document.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
  console.log('blur: ', event.target.id, document.activeElement.id)
}, true)

document.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
  console.log('focus: ', event.target.id, document.activeElement.id)
}, true)
```

```css
input { width: 3em; }
```

```html
<input id="a"> <input id="b"> <input id="c"> <input id="d"> <input id="e">
```

Comment: Фокус мне не подходит к сожалению, так как я использую обработчик в реакт приложении, фокус будет срабатывать на совсем другом компоненте - это путаница получится.